# How to stay at the same page after page reload in Angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have created a Sidebar consists of tabs by the following
[image]

In **ToDoList Tab** I have a form to be submitted, once pressing the submit button, the page reloads.

My question is, how do I stay on the **Todolist tab** that contains the form after the page reloads? When I reload the page, it navigates to the default **Dashboard** **tab**, which is different from the tab with the form.

```
onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.form.value);
  if (this.form.valid) {
    this.service.createform(this.form.value);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/todolist']);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't reload the page anymore. Handle the form submit event on the button's click event, and be sure to add `type="button"` to all the buttons that are located inside the `form` tag.

Comment: do you mind editing your question to add the contents of the function `this.service.createform` ?

Comment: if you want to stay there why are you navigating :)